# Pass Object from WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I have a WebService that I use to pass Restful API calls to a third party vendor to retrieve data.  In the WebService, I have a series of object classes defined to which I deserialize the data that is passed back in the response of the API call.

```
public GetOrgChartResponse GetOrgChart()
{
      GetOrgChartResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetOrgChartResponse>(request.Request_GET("/manage/v1/orgchart?node_id=5", Token, "Enrollment"));

      return response;
}
```

I also have a console application that consumes this WebService that I am using to execute some of the business logic that we need on these processes.  When I call the above function in the console application, I need to be able to return the above response into an identical "GetOrgChartResponse" object so that I can access its data members.  I tried to define an identical class object in my console application, but it is throwing errors that it is conflicting with the WebService's version of the object.

```
LMSWebService.ServiceClient client = new LMSWebService.ServiceClient();

LMSWebService.GetOrgChartResponse = client.GetOrgChart();
```

Is there a way for me to access the class object as a variable from the WebService so that I don't duplicate the class object in my console app code?  And if not, is there a way for me to use this object in my console app code so that it doesn't conflict with the WebService version?

Comment: Use a shared library with the definitions? Or auto-generate the client side.

Comment: I wanted to avoid shared libraries just due to the maintenance involved with independently maintaining two different codesets that are for the same application, but it gave me the idea to just create a shared library project within the same WebService solution so I don't have to maintain them separately.  Thank you.

Comment: Two different code sets? You just create one project for the shared library right?